# Should you query AWS dynamoDB directly from a swift app, or is it better to use a reverse proxy server and redirect to the database?

Tags: swift, nginx, amazon-dynamodb

For example, using an nginx server sitting within your AWS network?

Comment: Typically, you would build an API using AWS API Gateway and AWS Lambda that provides "access" to your DynamoDB. Otherwise, it would be hard to manage access to your DynamoDB (authentication/authorization). If you wanted another layer of abstraction on top of that, you can have a look at [AWS Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/).

Comment: Please explain your problem throughly, And it is recommended that you should do some R&D first then ask question here.